# Android gradle-experimental with databinding not working?

Tags: android, android-studio, data-binding, gradle-experimental

I had some troubles when I tried to use the latest Android building tool(gradle-experimental:0.6.0-alpha3) with databinding framework. It results in an error when I try to refresh all gradle projects.

*First*: `Error:Exception thrown while executing model rule: BaseComponentModelPlugin.Rules#createBinaryTasks > create(dataBindingExportBuildInfoAllDebug)`

```
model {
    ...
    android.dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    ...
}
```

*Second*: `Error:Cause: com.android.build.gradle.managed.AndroidConfig$Impl`

```
model {
    android {
        ...
        dataBinding {
            enabled = true
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Did you figure out how to use databinding with gradle-experimental?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
android.dataBinding {
    enabled true
}
```

Comment: I think you meant you used `enabled = true`? For me only with the `=` it worked.